# How can an app be restarted in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Can I force restart of an app in NS?

That is - close and restart.

Thanks

Can I force restart of an app in NS?

That is - close and restart.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code I'm using to restart the app:

import { android as and } from "@nativescript/core/application";

```
if (isAndroid) {
    const activity: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity = and.foregroundActivity;
    const intent: android.content.Intent = activity.getIntent();

    activity.finish();
    and.context.startActivity(intent);
} else if (isIOS) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Android app is restarted but the iOS app only closes and needs to be started manually. I still haven't figured out how to properly restart it.